# TEnum não identificado no html

Tags: c#, enums, asp.net-mvc-helper

Criei o seguinte helper:

```
public static HtmlString DropDownListEnum<TEnum>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, int? valorSelecionado = null)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> lstEnum = AttributesHelper.ToSelectList<TEnum>(valorSelecionado);

        MvcHtmlString html = htmlHelper.DropDownList(name, lstEnum, new object { });

        return html;
    }
```

E ao tentar chama-lo na View o TEnum foi identificado como uma tag do html.

```
@Html.DropDownListEnum<TipoObjetoEnum>("ddlTeste", Model.IdTipoObjetoFK)
```

[image: exemplo]

Como eu faço para que o html interprete `TipoObjetoEnum` como um TEnum ao invés de uma tag?

Comment: Veja se isto te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5285842/221800

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade o seu *Helper* não foi reconhecido pela *View*. Há duas formas de resolver:

#### 1. Fazendo `@using` na declaração da *View* do *namespace* onde o *Helper* foi implementado

```
@model SeuProjeto.Models.SeuModel
@using SeuProjeto.Helpers
```

#### 2. Colocando a declaração no `Web.config` de dentro do diretório `Views`

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="SeuProjeto" />
        <add namespace="SeuProjeto.Helpers" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

---

**EDIT**

Esqueci uma coisa importante: o Razor costuma interpretar sinais de abertura e fechamento de chaves como HTML. Para ele, é como se você estivesse escrevendo, por exemplo:

```
@Html.DropDownListEnum<div></div>("ddlTeste", Model.IdTipoObjetoFK)
```

O jeito de resolver é:

```
@(Html.DropDownListEnum<TipoObjetoEnum>("ddlTeste", Model.IdTipoObjetoFK))
```

Sim, horrível, eu sei.

Comment: Ambos estão no mesmo namespace, tanto que no Ctrl + Espace o método aparece para o auto complete.

Comment: @JonathanBarcela Implementei sua solução aqui e aumentei minha resposta. Veja se te atende.

Comment: Resolveu o meu problema. Obrigado :D